# How do you remove a trailing comma for a csvFile csvHelper, c#

Tags: c#, csv, parsing, csvhelper

I am at an impass in trying to parse this CsvFile. I am almost done but I ran into a problem.
My Header has 7 values, with there own properties, though one is blank at the end:

```
Measurement,Val,Val1,Val2,Val3,Error,Failed
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I am trying to print the above exactly like it is, but I ran into a problem where my output looks like this down below:

```
Measurement,Val,Val1,Val2,Val3,Error,Failed
1,2,3,4,5,6,
```

Here, after the 6 there is a trailing comma, where there should not be one. I used the ignore properties since there is no values for the Header "Failed" and it gave me that. My question is, how would I remove the trailing comma after 6?

Here is my code so far:

```
//Foo class is already defined
 public sealed class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
        {
            public FooMap()
            {
                Map(m => m.Measurement).Name("Measurement");//maps the variables from the class above to things in quotes
                Map(m => m.Val).Name("Val");
                Map(m => m.Val1).Name("Val1");
                Map(m => m.Val2).Name("Val2");

                Map(m => m.Val3).Name("Val3");
                Map(m => m.Error).Name("Error");
                //Map(m => m.Failed).Name("Failed");
                Map(m => m.Failed).Ignore();

            }
        }
void main()

 using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"path.csv"))
 using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
 csv.Read();
csv.Context.Record = csv.Context.Record.Reverse().SkipWhile(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace).Reverse().ToArray();
csv.ReadHeader();
var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);
}
```

I saw some suggest using csv.Context.Record, however for this one it is still not working and I am still receiving the trailing comma at the end after 6. How would I approach to making sure it is not there?

Comment: Why do you want to remove it?  The trailing comma is correct and valid CSV, indicating an empty value for the Failed column. Removing the comma would make it incorrect.

Comment: Try Trim(",") wchich will remove comma at end.